# Error in sql select statement

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, sql

I have the following method that uses to search for a text in a table

```
protected void fillGridView(int followingID, string text)
    {

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select t.*,u.firstName,u.lastName,u2.firstName as afirstName,u2.lastName as alastName ,i.icon,ii.iconPath as taskIcon, iii.iconPath as seenIcon,f.fileName,f.fileID from tasks as t inner join users as u on u.userID=t.addedBy inner join users as u2 on u2.userID=t.attachTo inner join priorityIcons as i on t.priority=i.priorityID inner join icons as ii on t.status=ii.iconName inner join icons as iii on t.isNew=iii.iconName left join files as f on t.fileID=f.fileID where t.followingID=@followingID and t.firstName LIKE '%asd%'");


        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@followingID", followingID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);            

        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
        DataSet ds = db.select(myCommand);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        tasksRepeater.DataSourceID = null;
        tasksRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //Here the exception appear because the dataset ds is "null" 
        tasksRepeater.DataBind();
        tasksCounter();
    }
```

And the exception Message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

but when i exchange sql statement above with the following one, the code runs successfully

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select t.*,u.firstName,u.lastName,u2.firstName as afirstName,u2.lastName as alastName ,i.icon,ii.iconPath as taskIcon, iii.iconPath as seenIcon,f.fileName,f.fileID from tasks as t inner join users as u on u.userID=t.addedBy inner join users as u2 on u2.userID=t.attachTo inner join priorityIcons as i on t.priority=i.priorityID inner join icons as ii on t.status=ii.iconName inner join icons as iii on t.isNew=iii.iconName left join files as f on t.fileID=f.fileID where t.followingID=@followingID");
```

so what is the problem!?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is an exception you get when you try to access something that hasn't been initialized yet. Figure out which value hasn't been initialized. The stack trace should indicate which line of code this is occurring on. Or you can debug and let it break when the exception is thrown. I'm guessing this has more to do with your control's lifecycle and something like `tasksRepeater` being null than your SQL.

Comment: The problem is in sql statement, i'm sure. because when i change the sql statement with another that not had 'like word' , code run successfully..

Comment: Based on the new information you've provided, I'd say you need to look at your `DBAccess` class and see under what circumstances it will return a `null` value instead of a Dataset. In fact, try stepping through that `select` method with a debugger and see exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not returning any rows, so when you do `ds.Tables[0]` it throws because `ds.Tables` is empty.

I suspect that your query has a typo, as you are setting the value of a `@text` parameter, but the parameter does not exist in the query. Your query probably needs to end with:

```
"...where t.followingID=@followingID and t.firstName LIKE '%@text%'"
```

That being said, your code should probably be able to deal with the case where the query returns no rows (you can check this by inspecting the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase.count.aspx) property on `ds.Tables`).

Comment: It's not so much that `ds.Tables` is empty, but that his `DBAccess.select()` method returned a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess error is in where clause. Please try using this query

```
"select t.*,u.firstName,u.lastName,u2.firstName as afirstName,u2.lastName as alastName ,i.icon,ii.iconPath as taskIcon, iii.iconPath as seenIcon,f.fileName,f.fileID from tasks as t inner join users as u on u.userID=t.addedBy inner join users as u2 on u2.userID=t.attachTo inner join priorityIcons as i on t.priority=i.priorityID inner join icons as ii on t.status=ii.iconName inner join icons as iii on t.isNew=iii.iconName left join files as f on t.fileID=f.fileID where t.followingID=@followingID and u.firstName LIKE '%asd%'"
```

Put u.FirstName instead of t.firstName.

I guess error is in alias for t.

try this.